# Repeating current iteration of a for loop given a condition inside the loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, repeat

I'm trying to simulate a polymer in 2D where a single polymer is constructed out of multiple monomers. The method of simulation is via randomizing the angle between two monomers. this is obviously a big simplification: every monomer is a line with a sphere at the end. the condition is that the spheres can not overlap. The problem that I'm having is that if indeed the spheres overlap the `continue` command finishes the current iteration but the monomer is not created, which means if 1 overlapping occurs there will be 1 less monomer than intended. What needs to happened is that if it overlaps it will try to build the monomer again until it doesn't overlap with any other monomer.  I tried a `while` loop but I'm building each monomer inside the loop so I couldn't figure it out.
The overlapping check (`check_monomer_distance`) needs to check every single monomer  that had been generated.
(I need to do this simulation in 3D as well but I'm focusing on 2D atm, that's why there is an unused variable `dim`)

```
import numpy as np
import random


dim = 2
monomer_length = 10
edge_diameter = 1  #radius of spheres
polymer_length = 100 # a single polymer is made out of many monomers of identical length
d_angle = 10


d_theta_range = np.arange(0.0, 2 * np.pi, d_angle)
last_coordinates= np.zeros(int(dim))
list_coo = [np.zeros(int(dim))] #every element in this list is the coordinates of a monomer, which means the polymer at its entirety 


for n_m in range(0, polymer_length): # n_m == Number of monomer
    random_d = random.choice(d_theta_range) # The angle between one monomer to the next
    step = monomer_length * np.array((np.cos(random_d), np.sin(random_d)))
    next_coordinates = last_coordinates + step
    if not check_monomer_distance(list_coo, next_coordinates, dim):  # check to see if monomers overlap
        continue
    last_coordinates = next_coordinates
    list_coo.append(next_coordinates)


def check_monomer_distance(list_coo, next_coordinates, dim):
    for i in range(len(list_coo)-1): # The minus 1 is because it will never overlap with the first previous monomer
        vector = next_coordinates - list_coo[i] # vector from the proposed monomer to every other generated
        vector_length = np.sqrt(vector[0]**2 + vector[1]**2)
        if vector_length < edge_diameter:
            return False # The return values need to be like this I can't change them: if the spheres overlap return False
        return True
```

I need to run some analyses at the end that's why the polymer is a list (`list_coo`), What interests me is the analyses not the polymer itself.
The randomization of the angle needs to be like this, its a bit of a hassle I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close: you described the logic accurately in words, but didn't implement it in your code.  This is a classic "until valid" loop, seen in many languages as "while not valid".

```
for n_m in range(0, polymer_length): # n_m == Number of monomer

    valid = False
    while not valid  # Repeat this loop until it generates a non-overlapping monomer.
        random_d = random.choice(d_theta_range) # The angle between one monomer to the next
        step = monomer_length * np.array((np.cos(random_d), np.sin(random_d)))
        next_coordinates = last_coordinates + step
        valid = check_monomer_distance(list_coo, next_coordinates, dim):

    last_coordinates = next_coordinates
    list_coo.append(next_coordinates)
```

Comment: Thank you very much I'm new to programming, I would have never figured this concept on my own. Follow up question: if the defined function would return the opposite Boolean you could reverse the valid to `True` and the `while` condition to `valid` from `not valid` correct?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?  What don't you understand about the result?  You seem to be trying to use Stack Overflow for tutorial help with a hypothetical situation.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to the website as well. Anyway thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using an extra variable by leveraging the while construct and continue/break statements

Using `break` to stop when condition is met:

```
for n_m in range(0, polymer_length): # n_m == Number of monomer
    while True: # repeat while condition is not met, break when it is
        random_d = random.choice(d_theta_range) # The angle between one monomer to the next
        step = monomer_length * np.array((np.cos(random_d), np.sin(random_d)))
        next_coordinates = last_coordinates + step
        if check_monomer_distance(list_coo, next_coordinates, dim):  # check to see if monomers overlap
            break
    last_coordinates = next_coordinates
    list_coo.append(next_coordinates)
```

Or using `continue` to loop when condition is not met:

```
for n_m in range(0, polymer_length): # n_m == Number of monomer
    while True: # continue loop until condition met, break when done
        random_d = random.choice(d_theta_range) # The angle between one monomer to the next
        step = monomer_length * np.array((np.cos(random_d), np.sin(random_d)))
        next_coordinates = last_coordinates + step
        if not check_monomer_distance(list_coo, next_coordinates, dim):  # check to see if monomers overlap
            continue
        last_coordinates = next_coordinates
        list_coo.append(next_coordinates)
        break
```